# Maximum possible parts of a cake if cut n times

Tags: puzzle

In how many maximum/minium parts can a round cake($\large\text{ cylinder}$) be divided with $n$ cuts when each cut is necessarily a straight line?

What would be the case if we have a circle,sphere,toroid,etc

Comment: The minimum amount seems to be trivial. With $n$ cuts you get $n+1$ pieces.

Comment: @DarthGeek Max??

Comment: The phrasing of your questions makes it unclear whether this is a 2-d or 3-d problem. Are we cutting with planes or lines?

Comment: The sphere case will be the same as the cylinder case if so.

Comment: I am cutting with planes

Comment: I guess you need to specify if the cake slices can be rearranged after each cut.

Comment: Do they have to be vertical planes, or are horizontal planes and slanting planes allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as the lazy caterer's sequence, the number is $\frac{n(n+1)+2}{2}$. The idea is to use Euler's Formula $E-V+F=2$ and the fact that the number of edges increases $1$ more than the number of vertices in each line.

Comment: I have a cylinder not a circle

Comment: However I am sure that the problem can be solved using a similar technique.

Comment: @HashirOmer The wikipedia article [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_caterer's_sequence) also mentions the so called "cake number", which is the 3D equivalent you are looking for.

Comment: When $n=3$ your formula gives $7$ pieces. However, if the centroid of the cake is at the origin, the three coordinate planes cut it into $8$ pieces. Are you assuming some restriction on the cutting planes that is not stated in the question?

Comment: yes thank you, what I gave is for 2d, the formula for 3-d is given in kneldsepp's comment, the cake number.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to say $2^n$ in dimension $n$ for $n$ cut, because you can always find a hyperplane (I consider a cut being a hyperplane) cutting all the ones already drawn... At least, with one cut (line cut, of course) you can only double the number of parts, so $2^n$ is an easy upper bound, and the previous argument should work properly written.

For the plane case (usual cake without horizontal cut), I'd like to say $2n$, but you can do much more, cutting a bit away from the center : with 3 cuts you get not 6 but 7 parts.

With one cut you can at best double the number of parts, but of course you should try to keep the maximum number of part intersecting one half of the cake (cutting implies not cutting in one half plane !)...

Well, merely some thoughts.

Comment: In case the pieces are allowed to be moved this is certainly correct.

Comment: is it possible to get 2^n pieces without moving pieces/changing their orientations? In 3 cut it simple to visualize that 8 pieces can be made(2 vertical cut and 1horizontal) but how to get 16 pieces from these 8 pieces and just using 1 more cut. I not able to think of any hyper-plane for this.()